# Is it possible to create area as Shared library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shared-libraries, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an ASP .NET MVC app, that contains multiple areas, for better organisation I would like to separete them into shared library projects. So every area has its own project, is this even possible? How can I do that ?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you need Backoffice and Frontoffice you could create 2 different ASP.NET MVC apps for it. I don't see any reason why you should separate your areas.

Comment: Apps will run on the same hosted IIS. So I can have only one app

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx, but i won't do this. Just because every area has an AreaRegistration file, that doesn't mean we must abuse

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to reference area as dll. There is nice article on this [blog](http://blog.falafel.com/work-asp-net-mvc-5-areas-different-projects/)